# railsのテンプレートで配列をインデックスを指定して参照したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsでレビューサイトを作っています。
レビューには画像を何枚か添付して投稿ができて、レビューの一覧ページでは、
レビューのタイトルや本文の冒頭とともに、投稿された一枚目の写真のみ表示するようにしたいです。

下記コードにあるように、loopをまわさずに書きたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか?

```
  <%# こういうことがやりたいが後述のエラーが出てしまう %>
  <%= image_tag review.pictures[0].image　%>

  <%# 仕方なくループを使って、 一度目のループで無理やりbreakして一枚だけ表示してる %>
  <% review.pictures.each do |picture| %>
    <%= image_tag picture.image %>
    <% break %>
  <% end %>
```

一個目の書き方だと、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Showing /Users/xxxx/rails/yyyy/app/views/reviews/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `image　' for #<Picture:0x007fbcbf7bafd8>
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= image_tag review.pictures[0].image　%>`
ですが imageの後に全角のスペースが入ってますよ。そのためエラーが出てます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かにそうなっていて修正したらうまくいきました。

Comment: @tatsuya.yokoyama 解決した場合は回答にチェックをお願いします。チェックがないと未解決として残ってしまいます。またチェックを入れると質問者の信頼度も高まります。